# Has the use of sudo changed in Debian 7?

Tags: debian, sudo

I will try to explain my situation first. I am currently running 6 virtualized Debian servers on a ESXi host machine. The virtual servers where installed with a Debian Linux 6 (Lenny).

Recently I updated the servers to debian Wheezy

```
root@ares> lsb_release -a                                                                                                    /home/vincent
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
Release:        7.1
Codename:       wheezy
```

it has come to my attention that since this upgrade the 'sudo' command is displaying weird behaviour. Actually, it seems to have no effect at all. I checked the /etc/visudo file and everything seems ok. Sudo also asks for my password but then does not seem to run things as root. 
An example is the 'ifconfig' command:

```
user@ares> ifconfig 
zsh: command not found: ifconfig
[127] user@ares> sudo ifconfig
sudo: ifconfig: command not found
[1] user@ares> sudo su
root@ares>ifconfig  
output shows
```

anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: Check your `PATH`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thx. This seems to be the issue. Could you post this as answer? Mystery tough how my path has changed after the upgrade...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `PATH` probably differs between your normal user and the root user, likely missing directories such as `/sbin` and/or `/usr/sbin` where administrative utilities like `ifconfig` normally live.

Comment: I think the OP is complaining that sudo as configured no longer changes the PATH for sudo commands.  If that's right, your answer isn't, though it points in the right general direction for finding the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Michael's answer is correct, but I wanted to add a comment:

It is not mandatory to add administrative commands' path (`/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/local/sbin`) to an unprivileged user, as long as the `secure_path` directive is configured in `/etc/sudoers` on in your LDAP server, if you use an LDAP backend:

```
$ ip a s
-rbash: ip: command not found

$ sudo ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:57:80:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.197.38/24 brd 172.22.197.255 scope global eth0

$ echo $PATH
/home/dawud/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

$ sudo -l | awk '$0~/secure_path/ {print $1}'
secure_path=/bin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/local/sbin
```

Check `man 5 sudoers` for further reference on `secure_path` (also of interest are `exempt_group` and `env_reset`).

```
 secure_path   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don’t trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if you want to
               have the “root path” be separate from the “user path”.  Users in the group specified by the exempt_group option are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not set by default.
```

Comment: Very useful, and much better than the answer marked as correct.  only thing is that `man sudoers(5)` is not a valid command.  Maybe different people do things differently(?), but I reckon if you're going to refer to sudoers(5) you should talk about the "sudoers(5) man page", not `man 5 sudoers`.  Nitpicky to be sure.  Edited.